# ¿Como obtengo el ID del label actual?

Tags: javascript, php, html, formularios

tengo un formulario que cuando dan clic en añadir, agrega un campo al fomulario de forma dinamica utilizando JS.

Basicamente lo que hace es duplicar esto:

```
Cuota 1: <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" />
```

Con JS

```
// create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
            var newElem = $('#input' + num).clone().attr('id', 'input' + newNum);

            // manipulate the name/id values of the input inside the new element
            newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);

            // insert the new element after the last "duplicatable" input field
            $('#input' + num).after(newElem);
```

Lo que no logro es aumentar el "Cuota 1" que esta por fuera.

Estaba intentando capturar el ID del elemento para imprimirlo con un:

```
document.write(document.getElementById(this.id).id);
```

Pero no fui capaz.

Alguna sugerencia para aumentar ese valor?

https://jsbin.com/xoxexofavi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Puedes añadir ese `Cuota X` como un `<label>` desde JavaScript para que así puedas modificar el texto a mostrar.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/xoxexofavi/1/edit?html,output  Aqui tengo un ejemplo de como esta funcionando, pero no lo logro @Alexis88

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo logre utilizando un pseudoelemento

Puede que no quieras que se vea el inventario como una cajita de input. No hay problema. Podrías usar una propiedad del label (ej rel) para almacenar el stock disponible, y poner un seudoelemento que desplegara la cantidad de stock sin tocar el texto, sino usando un atributo. Por ejemplo, piensa que defines el stock del producto 1 usando:

```
<div class="item" id="i1">
   <label class="stock" rel="10">Stock </label>
</div>
```

Y en la hoja de estilos carro.css le pones un seudoelemento cuyo contenido es el atributo rel del label:

```
.item .stock:after {
    content: attr(rel);
    width: 20px;
}
```

Entonces, cuando quisieras conocer el stock disponible usarías:

```
$(".item").each(function() {
  var relInventario = $(this).attr('rel'); 
  var inventario = parseInt(relInventario, 10);
  if(inventario > 0) {
     $(this).on("dblclick", dobleClickItems);
  }
});
```

Y para modificar el inventario:

```
inventario--;
$(this).attr('rel',inventario);
```

o con newElem.find

```
newElem.find(':div').attr({id: name + newNum, name: name + newNum, rel: newNum});
```